# how to add vertical gesture in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

how do i add straight vertical slide in UIPanGestureRecognizer on image. i have some code:

```
- (IBAction)HandlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner
{
    CGPoint translation = [panner translationInView:panner.view];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.center.x + translation.x, self.pesawat.center.y);

    int offset = 80; // pixels to offset

    if (newCenter.x < offset)
        newCenter = CGPointMake(offset, newCenter.y);
    else if (newCenter.x > self.view.bounds.size.width - offset) 
        newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - offset, newCenter.y);

    self.pesawat.center = newCenter;
    [panner setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:panner.view];
}
```

if i change code to like this:

```
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.center.x + translation.x, self.pesawat.center.y + translation.y);
```

it's become dragable(horizontal,vertical,diagonal too), what i want is just to make it's straight vertical and horizontal without image to move diagonal

and this viewdidload:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
[panner addTarget:self action:@selector(HandlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panner];
```

could anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint translation = [panner translationInView:panner.view];
if (translation.x > translation.y)
    translation.y = 0.0f;
else
    translation.x = 0.0f;

CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.pesawat.center.x + translation.x, self.pesawat.center.y + translation.y);
```

This will only apply the bigger part of `translation`.

Comment: what do you mean by apply the bigger part?